# Xhr upload support on Cross Domain requests

Tags: upload, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

I have a proxy that uploads a fire to the Amazon S3 Server. This proxy is made using NodeJS and my webpage is hosted on a Tomcat server. So to make a Xhr upload I had to use Nginx to solve the cross domain issues as the both servers are on the same machine.

But using Nginx has a lot of issues so my boss asked if I can do the same thing using a Cross Domain Policy. I've made it but that is some things that I'm not being able to do. Here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {};
xhr.open('POST', self.basePath + '/upload' + file.name, true, null, null, null, true,       true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.sendAsBinary(file.getAsBinary());
```

This works on a Cross Domain Request reaching the Server with the file and returning the response, but when I try to set a progress event like these:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {};
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(){console.info('on progress');};
xhr.open('POST', self.basePath + '/upload' + file.name, true, null, null, null, true,       true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.sendAsBinary(file.getAsBinary());
```

The Cross Domain Request isn't fired ( the request uses a "OPTIONS" method instead of POST and it never reaches the server ). But, as you may think, I need the progress event to show it to the user. Does anyone knows what is happening??

Ps: All of the codes above works perfectly on a "same domain" request.
Ps2: I've tried xhr.onprogress but it is never fired ( on cross or same domain requests )
Ps3: I've tried on FF4+ and Chrome 12+

Thanks A LOT.
Thiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem before.

**Solution**: Add

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

in your CORS configuration on s3

Answer (score 1):

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", yourUpdateProgressFunction, false);
```